# highcharts display data from different months

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have an highcharts chart where my yAxis is 24 hours of the day and the xAxis is the date . I am facing a problem when I want to display two months on the same chart.
for instences with only one month like this:

```
data:[{
             x:Date.UTC(2020,10,25),
             low:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,20,0,0),
             high:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,22,0,0)
            }]
```

the chart display the graph perfectly.
However, when the data contain more than one month, like here:

```
{
         type:'columnrange',
         data:[{
             x:Date.UTC(2020,10,25),
             low:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,20,0,0),
             high:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,22,0,0)
            }]
         },
         {
          type:'columnrange',
          data:[{
             x:Date.UTC(2020,11,1),
             low:Date.UTC(2020,11,1,20,0,0),
             high:Date.UTC(2020,11,1,22,0,0)
            }]
        }
```

the data exist but it is not being displayed on the chart.

here are the chart's options.

```
this._options={
    chart:{
        type:'columnrange'
        },
    series:[
        {
         type:'columnrange',
         data:[{
             x:Date.UTC(2020,10,25),
             low:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,20,0,0),
             high:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,22,0,0)
            }]
         },
         {
          type:'columnrange',
          data:[{
             x:Date.UTC(2020,11,1),
             low:Date.UTC(2020,11,1,20,0,0),
             high:Date.UTC(2020,11,1,22,0,0)
            }]
        }],
    yAxis:{
          min:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,0,0,0),
          max:Date.UTC(2020,10,25,23,59,59)
          type:'datetime',
          labels:{
               formatter:function(){
                    return dateFormat('%H:%M',this.value);
                }
            }
         opposite:false
         },
    xAxis:{
         minorTickInterval:24*3600*1000,
         min:Date.UTC(2020,10,25),
         max:Date.UTC(2020,11,1),
         type:'datetime',
         labels:{
             align:'center',
             formatter:function(){
                 return dateFormat('%e / %m / %y',this.value);
               }
             }
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and it seems that the points are outside the range of the  `min` and `max` values which you have set.

Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgjfhxds/

Comment: I did what you've suggested and it works perfectly, but now ,when the min max options are disabled, the yAxis displays wider range than what I need. Do you have any solution so it will work and display only 24 hours on the yAxis . Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How would you like to display only 24 hours on the yAxis if the range between those two points is one month? In this case, you will need to change the data format.

Comment: I don't want to display only 24 hours. I do want to display only the hours of the points on yaxis and the date on xAxis. For example if i need to display  GAP store opening hours, so the xAxis presents the dates within the month and the yAxis will display the hours, so the low value is the opening hour and the high value is the closing one.

Comment: `so the xAxis presents the dates within the month and the yAxis will display the hours, so the low value is the opening hour and the high value is the closing one.` I think that you just answered your question ;) As you mentioned, you want to display just hours on the yAxis, which means that you will need to change your low and high data. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4z30qnge/